# Tries Data Structure - Print All Values

Tags: c, loops, recursion, data-structures, trie

I want to print all the values in my trie data structure, as well as this code is the parts of dictionary program.

```
void search(struct dictionary **current) {
    if((*current)->is_end==1){
        printf("\n"); getchar();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
        if((*current)->Children[i]!=NULL){
            printf("%c",i+(int)'a');
            search(&(*current)->Children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to push the values.

1. "false"
2. "fail"

but when I run that code, the program just shows:
fail
lse

the parts "fa" of "false" doesn't showing because the recursion doesn't start from beginning again if is_end has been marked.

Comment: "*the parts "fa" of "false" doesn't showing because the recursive don't start from beginning again if is_end has been marked.*" -- It sounds like you've already found the answer on your own.

Comment: Why are you passing double pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the recursion from the begining every time you reach a terminal node. You can just keep the buffer with the current prefix when you traverse the trie and print its entire content every time is_end is true.